# Python: Filling up strings of variable length

Tags: python, list, tuples, string-length

I have a collection of strings of variable length that I'm trying to fill up with  text from a list. The whole setup should look something like this:

**Input:**

```
list_of_string_lengths = [5, 8, 10]
list_of_words = ["this", "is", "some", "text"]
```

**Output:**

```
list_of_strings = ["this", "is some", "text"]
```

From another answer on stackoverflow I got this snippet:

```
def truncate(s_tuples, max_length):

    def stop_iterator(s_tuples):
        tot_len = 0
        for s,num in s_tuples:
            tot_len += get_words_number(s)
            if tot_len >= max_length:
                if tot_len == max_length:
                    yield s
                break
            yield s

    return ' '.join(stop_iterator(s_tuples))
```

with

```
for word in list_of_words:
    w_tuples.append(word, len(word))
```

using

```
for length in list_of_lengths:
    wanted_string = truncate(w_tuples, length)
    list_of_strings.append(wanted_string)
```

I get strings of the correct length, but they obviously always start at the beginning of the word list.

I tried adding

```
w_tuples = w_tuples[len(wanted_string.split()):]
```

to the end of the loop, but this resulted in this:

```
list_of_strings = ["this is some text", "", ""]
```

What am I missing? Is there another, better way to get the result that I want?

Comment: So you need not only strings of the right length, but randomly selected strings rather than the "first" matching ones?

Comment: Sorry if this wasn't clear: The strings should be returned in sequence, not randomly.
So in this example the result should always be somewhere between ["this","is","some","text"] and ["this is some text"], depending on the allowed length.